# Paramiko equvalent of pipline controls and input/output pipes

Tags: python, file, transfer, paramiko

I need a method of paramiko based file transfer with a lightweight [SSH2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Version_2.0) server ([dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html)) which has no support for [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) or [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol). Is there a way of achieving a cat and redirect style file transfer, such as:

```
ssh server "cat remote_file" > local_file
```

with [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) channels?

Can paramiko.Transport.open_channel() or Message() do the job? I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Corrected error in original question. The limitation is the SSH server not the SSH client.

Answer (score 1):

If the limitation, as you say, is only in your client, you can easily implement a SFTP client directly with paramiko -- e.g., look at this [example](http://commandline.org.uk/python/sftp-python/) code.

Answer (score 1):

pyfilesystem implements an [sftp filesystem](http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/source/browse/trunk/fs/sftpfs.py) on top of paramiko.